# SharePoint 2010 data storage location

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sql, sharepoint-2010

Where exactly is SharePoint storing all of the data? I installed the server in the default location but I'd like it to have it save the data on a different drive. The setup did not prompt for any such setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's in the database.  I would start with [this series of videos](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518660.aspx) to get started.  In particular module 2 has the details on exactly how sharepoint stores it's data and configurations